# How can I make fugitive-vim show the commit message for each line in the file?

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I used to be able to do `:Gblame` in a file and see the author and commit message for each line in the file. But that setup is lost. In my current `vimrc` setup I get this output:

`d94c4702 src/components/questions/Question.tsx 30 (Martin 2017-11-29>|`

I'd love to format it to look something like this:
`$sha $commit_message`

Any idea how I can make that happen?

Comment: Do you want `git blame` or `git log`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember ever seeing a commit summary (1st line of commit) with `:Gblame`. I see the following: sha, author, date/time, text.

However you can use [Fugitive Blame Extension](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-fugitive-blame-ext) to echo the commit message summary.